# Nested OL digit.digit style list for IE7 (and below) - Javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, nested, html-lists

This was hinted at in another post, but I need some assistance with displaying a list like this in IE7

```
1. 
   a. 
   b. 
         1.0 
         2.0 
           2.1 
2.
```

I think I am limited to JavaScript because of IE7's lack of CSS :before support. For example, this does **not** work

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a complete solution, but I have found a partial solution to this problem. Please refer to the Blog post [Techy Treasures #5: Fudging CSS Counters in Internet Explorer](http://www.sitepoint.com/techy-treasures-5-fudging-css-counters-in-internet-explorer/)